# Are DirectX 12 "Full Screen Exclusive Windows" forced to run at the same refresh rate as DWM?

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, dwm, dxgi

I recently read an [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/demystifying-full-screen-optimizations/) that mentioned DirectX 12's exclusive fullscreen windows are essentially borderless fullscreen windows, which fall under the control of DWM. Given that DWM operates based on the refresh rate chosen in the display settings, does this mean it's not possible to configure a swapchain in DirectX 12 with a different refresh rate from the display setting?

After examining this [DirectX12 sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/UWP/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp) from microsoft, I've noticed they don't specify a refresh rate for fullscreen transitions. This makes me assume that fullscreen windows use DWM's refresh rate. Can someone verify this?

Comment: The refresh rate subject has been a changing area these last years, and it has become quite complicated. Energy consumption is an important subject. It depends on your context, but with variable refresh rate (VRR) displays (which is supposed to be good for everyone), you shouldn't care too much. Don't use FSE. Most sample from Microsoft don't use it, enable tearing when available, and send your frames when they're ready. Or  use compositor clock (Windows 11 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/compositor-clock/compositor-clock)

Answer (score 3):

> Given that DWM operates based on the refresh rate chosen in the display settings, does this mean it's not possible to configure a swapchain in DirectX 12 with a different refresh rate from the display setting?

No, DWM will operate at the refresh rate specified by [DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1-getfullscreendesc) passed to [CreateSwapChainForHwnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforhwnd)

> After examining this DirectX12 sample from microsoft

That sample isn't using Fullscreen Exclusive/Optimizations. It's just borderless windowed (which will use the DWM refresh rate).

You can make it FSE by passing a valid pointer instead of nullptr [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/b5f92e2251ee83db4d4c795b3cba5d470c52eaf8/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp#L134) in the desktop sample.

**Edit**: Actually if `m_tearingSupport` is false then it will use FSE (i.e. FSE=`SetFullscreenState`, Borderless Windowed=`SetWindowPos`), the refresh rate will probably just be that of the DWM as you said. It depends on which path it takes [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/b5f92e2251ee83db4d4c795b3cba5d470c52eaf8/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Fullscreen/src/D3D12Fullscreen.cpp#L685).

For UWP, I have not idea whether `ApplicationView::TryEnterFullScreenMode` does FSE or not, and cant see anyway to configure the refresh rate.

Comment: just to be clear that i understood correctly; the window (when in FSE) will respect the refresh mode provided in the fullscreen desc, but since they didn't pass any in the sample, it will use the one already active (from dwm / display settings)?

Comment: @justasking yes, if the refresh rate changes the monitor undergoes a mode change which you should recognize if you have played video games. No mode change means it is using the same refresh rate